# phonegap-googlemaps-plugin shows blank screen

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

I am trying to setup googlemap into a demo app by following along with this tutorial (https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Tutorial-for-Windows).

Now the app does run, but it show an empty map that look like this:

[image]

I have tried to troubleshoot it via this guide (https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/TroubleShooting:-Blank-Map).

Everything I have done seems correct. No error or anything to trace what has been done wrong. I am testing it on real device. How can I fix it?

Comment: How about your code, bro?

Comment: @MrNeo My code is exactly the same as the tutorial, because I am follow everything and copy and paste the code from it.

Comment: I think you should add map options: `center`, `zoom` when creating map.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be because of incorrect API key. Same thing is happening with me but by changing the API key, it resolved the problem.